# Why isn't this pointer dereferenced?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, gcc

I've noticed that when printing a string via a pointer that **the pointer should not be dereferenced**. Why?

```
$ cat c.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char foo[] = "Meirav";
    char *bar = foo;

    printf("%s\n", foo);
    printf("%s\n", bar); // Why isn't this dereferenced?
    printf("%p\n", bar);

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
$ gcc -Wextra c.c
$ ./a.out
Meirav
Meirav
0x7fffda789ae0
```

This is the result of dereferencing the pointer, I receive both a compiler warning and a runtime error:

```
$ vim c.c
$ grep '&bar' c.c
        printf("%s\n", &bar);
$ gcc -Wextra c.c
c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:8:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("%s\n", &bar);
  ^
$ ./a.out
Meirav
��~|�
0x7fff7c7eafa0
```

**Why shouldn't the pointer dereferenced?**

This is my environment:

```
$ uname -a
Linux melancholy 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.13.0-48-generic (buildd@orlo) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS \n \l
```

Comment: `&bar` doesn't dereference the pointer `bar`. It gives the address of the pointer, which is a `char**`. Dereference=`*bar`

Comment: Why do you think it should?

Comment: why should it be? `"%s"` expects a pointer to char. `bar` is a pointer to char

Comment: @bolov: Thank you, your comment makes the issue clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a confusion, the `&` is the address of operator, so suppose you had this

```
char  string[] = "Meirav";
char *foo      = string;
char **bar     = &foo;
```

then you would need to dereference the pointer to a pointer, to get the `char` pointer that must be passed to `printf()` when you use the `"%s"` specifier, like this

```
printf("%s\n", *bar); /* Why isn't this dereferenced? */
/*             ^ dereference operator                 */
```

Note that the `&` operator, creates a pointer with the address of the variable, in this case the variable is a pointer, hence it's the address of the pointer, so you need to dereference the pointer with the `*` dereference operator, in order to pass it to `printf()`.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize that %s expects a pointer and that `char  string[] = "Meirav";` is essentially a pointer.